# How to get Notepad++ to open files properly in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, notepad++

For some reason in Windows 8 if I try to open a file in Notepad++ by either rightclick > "Edit witrh Notepad++" or by rightclick > open with > Notepad++ it will only bring NPP to the foreground, but not open the file. The only way to open a file seems to be with the open/browse button in NPP. This is far less efficient, as I already found the file, and must then find it a second time through the file browser.

This is obviously a bug in either NPP, Win 8, or my system. Is anyone else experiancing this? if so, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the latest build of N++? The one from Oct, 10?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I noticed the problem I downloaded it and reinstalled. This did not fix it.

Comment: Would you happen to know what build you were using before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run Notepad++ as an administrator (either by editing the shortcut, launching in admin manually, or by escalating for an upgrade, etc.), then it will do this until you close Notepad++ so that next time it launches it won't be in admin mode.

In other words, User mode Explorer doesn't like sending files to Admin mode Notepad++, but since only one instance can be run at a time, you have to close the admin mode version.

Or, you can leave it in admin mode and do a Notepad++ File->Open to the same file and it will open fine.

Comment: Beutiful, I didn't even realize my shortcut was set to admin mode, strange. But it worked.

Comment: For more information, this issue existed in Windows 7 (and probably Vista as well), and would drive me crazy since after every upgrade, I'd have to close and restart to run as a standard user.

Comment: Hm but unfortunately it needs to be run as admin to edit the hosts file, so that's rather annoying.

Comment: damn, that explains this annoying case